Why can't I deploy project (passenger wsgi)
When I change the passenger_wsgi.py to
import <project_name>.wsgi
application = <project_name>.wsgi.application

I encounter with below error:

Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger(R) application server.
Please read the Passenger log file (search for the Error ID) to find the details of the error.

I change wsgi.py in project to:
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.settings"

